# Delete rows if multiple cells have zero

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple Excel workbooks that contain about 8,000 rows so it would be nice to use a macro.

Basically, if any row has a zero (0) in all columns (at the same time) B, D, E, I, J, and K it will delete.

Here is what I have so far...way too new with VB to figure out.

```
Sub DeleteRowsZeros()
    Dim LR As Long, i As Long
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LR To 1 Step -1
        If (Range("B") = "0" And Range("D" & i) = "0" And Range("E" & i) = "0" And Range("I" & i) = "0" _
        And Range("J" & i) = "0" And Range("K" & i) = "0") Then Rows(i).Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) `Range("B")`-->`Range("B" & i)` 2) it's not clear what is the question

Comment: My code isn't working.  Keep getting a error.  Looking for advice on what's wrong

Comment: how exactly it's not working? what errors?

Comment: Run-time error '13' - Type mismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
Sub DeleteRowsZeros()
    Dim cell As Range, notZeroColumns As Range, row As Range

    Set row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).EntireRow.Offset(1, 0)
    Set notZeroColumns = Range("B:B,D:E,I:k")

    While row.row <> 1
        Set row = row.Offset(-1, 0)

        For Each cell In Intersect(row, notZeroColumns)
            If cell.Text <> "0" Then GoTo continueLbl
        Next

        row.Offset(1, 0).Delete
continueLbl:
    Wend
End Sub
```

EDIT : bugfixe

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  No errors, rows won't delete.

Comment: Weird, just tried it on my PC and everything run as expected. However I remarked that row 1:1 will not be deleted (just edited my answer)

Comment: You are right Seb, your script works just fine on a test spreadsheet. There is something going on with my spreadsheet that is affecting macros.  Can't figure it out at the moment and it is beyond the scope of my initial question.  Thanks for your help though.

Comment: You're welcome !  Please consider marking this answer as Answered (even if it is not mandatory).